# PHP Regex (.*?) and callback \\1 JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, regex

In PHP I have this (from previous question on my account):

```
$message = 'Testing this **quote**';
$search = '/\*\*(.*?)\\*\*/';
$replace = '<span style="font-weight: bold;">\\1</span>';
```

This works fine.

In JavaScript I have this:

```
var regexFind = document.getElementById("regexFind").innerHTML;
var pattern = /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gi;
var match = regexFind.match(pattern);
var result = regexFind.split(pattern).join("<span style='font-weight: bold;'>**\\1**</span>");
document.getElementById("regexOutput").innerHTML=result;
```

But as you can see in the `var result` I use the `\\1` but the output is:
`**\1**test**\1***` instead of a bold **test**, is there a JavaScript equivalent for PHP's `\\1`

Are my methods WAY off? Answer with a better (and working) method.  If possible.

`EDITS / RESPONSES`
When trying the `$1` method as [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) suggested:

```
var result = regexFind.split(pattern).join("<span style='color: red;'>**$1**</span>");
```

It outputs:
`**$1**test**$1**`

Comment: Have you tried `$1`, as per [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example:_Switching_words_in_a_string)?

Comment: @nnnnnn, just tried, didn't work.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I was talking about what works for `.replace()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, because it was handy for my last project, so I just decided to copy and paste, also, I edited my answer to say:
`Are my methods WAY off? Answer with a better (and working) method. If possible.`

Comment: I see that you have an escaping disease. Why in the world are you escaping twice in `\*\*(.*?)\\*\*` and in `\\1` ? Just use `\*\*(.*?)\*\*` and `\1`. You might even use `$1` in php. Check this [out](https://eval.in/116702). One more thing, there is no need to use the `i` modifier in your JS regex. Since you have no letters in your expression.

Comment: @HamZa Thanks for all the extra tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of `.match()` and `.join()`, and then you can refer to the first sub-match as `$1`:

```
var result = regexFind.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gi,
                               '<span style="font-weight: bold;">$1</span>');
```

(If there was a second sub-match it'd be `$2`, and so forth.)